# spring boot kubernetes ingress nginx Whitelabel Error Page login redirect

Tags: spring-boot, nginx-reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I want to run my spring boot application (with ui) via following  kubernetes ingress nginx configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test123xxx.com
      secretName: letsencrypt-staging
  rules:
    - host: test123xxx.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/?(.*)"
            backend:
              serviceName: application
              servicePort: 8080
```

If i call test123xxx.com, it will redirected to test123xxx.com/login (becaouse of spring-boot security config) but i get **Whitelabel Error Page** with **Http 404**

I can run the application via kubectl port-forward without any problem.

Comment: What is your path on which the /login is invoked?? Also did you try changing the context path? It seems like a context path error.

Comment: My login path is /login. As i described above, the application works fine.

Comment: Is it solved? Why did you put `path: "/?(.*)"`?

Comment: try to dig into the service and find out whether it is accessible on the nodePort. If yes, examine the nginx.conf in your ingress-controller pod.